# JNDI not passing credentials with lookup

Tags: jms, jndi, weblogic-10.x, tibco-ems

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.3 to define a connection to a foreign Tibco JMS queue.

I have setup:

- A JMS Module

  - Added foreign server details including

    - tibco initial context factory
    - jndi connection url
    - jndi properties credential
    - set java.naming.security.principal
  - Added 2 foreign destinations
  - Setup a foreign connection factory details including user name and password.

In my code I'm doing a simple lookup from JNDI.

```
QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) _context.lookup(JNDI_JMS_FACTORY_NAME);
```

Since I have the credentials in the configuration on weblogic, I expect the following should work.

```
QueueConnection connection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
```

However, I get: 
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Failed to connect to any server at: *server* [Error: authentication failed: url that returned this exception = *server* ]

If I pass the credentials then it works fine.

```
    QueueConnection connection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(user, password);
```

However, using this approach I must secure my credentials within my code.  Any thoughts as to why the parameterless createQueueConnection fails to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation provides the answer.  Make sure you use Container

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13727/j2ee.htm#JMSPG367